# Как добавить действие к кнопке в TableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Идея: вывожу в tableview данные клиента(ФИО) и также его номер телефона в виде кнопки "Позвонить". 
Все получается кроме кнопки. Как привязать к кнопке номер?
Данные получаю через AppDelegate в ViewController в виде:

```
NSMutableArray  *messages;
```

Как я понял нужно в:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Добавить что-то типа:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

А как передать в созданный @selector(action) полученный номер?

Comment: Добавил в CustomTableCell кнопку, сделал аутлеты-проперти.
`В VC добавил:[cell.callButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callMe) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

`-(void)callMe{
    NSLog(@"WWOOOOA!");
}`

Но не работает..

Comment: Вывести в логи "WWOOOOA!" при нажатии на кнопку получилось. Теперь другая проблема :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в CustomTableCell IBAction от кнопки.
В CustomTableCell.m  получится что-то типа этого:

```
- (IBAction)callMe:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"WWOOOOA!");
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //...
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(callMe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// ...
}

- (void)callMe:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", sender.titleLabel.text);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Еще вопрос: я получаю данные с сервера(ФИО+номер телефона) и вывожу через TableView.
В таблице, в каждой TableViewCell должна быть кнопка "Позвонить". Вопрос: как передать кнопкам свой соответсвующий номер телефона?
Данные хранятся в NSMutableArray *messages;

Comment: Для первого варианта:
Добавить в CustomTableCell.h проперти
@property (nonatomic) NSString *phoneNumber;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.phoneNumber = ...
}

- (IBAction)callMe:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@%@", self.phoneNumber);
}

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Получилось:)